# What is the format for a PointField in a django fixture?

Tags: json, django, gis, geodjango, django-fixtures

Suppose I have the following django model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    point = models.PointField()
```

And I want to load the [PointField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/gis/model-api/#pointfield) from a fixture. What is the format of the point field for a json fixture?

```
[
    {
    "model": "myapp.Location",
    "pk": 1,
    "fields": {
        "name": "Location Number 1",
        "point": "???",
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears to use the [Well-known text (WKT) format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text_representation_of_geometry)

For example, the following worked with `python manage.py loaddata myfixture.json`:

```
[
    {
    "model": "myapp.Location",
    "pk": 1,
    "fields": {
        "name": "Location Number 1",
        "point": "POINT (30 10)",
    }
  }
]
```

This successfully imported into postgresql database column with the type `point geometry(Point,4326)`.

If you were using another type such as a [PolygonField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/gis/model-api/#polygonfield), then presumably the format would be for example:

```
POLYGON ((30 10, 40 40, 20 40, 10 20, 30 10))
```

Comment: What would be the format if I am using a StringLine ?

Comment: @ErnestoRuiz I assume `LINESTRING (30 10, 10 30, 40 40)`, see the wikipedia article I linked to.